# Windows Batch: Rename a folder to the name of a file inside

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, renaming

I have ~3000 folders, each with multiple files in it. Each folder contains a txt file, with a few other file types. The folder names are hashed, so right now it's a jumble of random digits. I want to rename each folder to the same name as the txt file that is inside that folder. For example:

```
123456/myfile.txt
```

Should become:

```
myfile/myfile.txt
```

The folders do not contain any subfolders, if that matters.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (
  for %%b in ("%%a\*.txt") do (
    ECHO ren "%%a" "%%~nb"
  )
)
```

use a `for /d` to iterate over your folders and another plain `for` to get the filename (assuming, there is exactly one .txt file in each folder). `%%~nb` gets the name only without extension).

NOTE: after troubleshooting, remove the `ECHO` to enable the rename command.

Comment: This worked perfectly, it was just what I needed. Thank you!